# Can't Enable Wifi on Dell Laptop running 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, dell, tp-link

For my work I need to keep 16.04 LTS on a dual-boot system, but it seems there's a bug where either the correct firmware or drivers aren't loading for my adapter.  Now I've attached a Tp-Link Wireless Adapter (T4U V1.0) and installed the drivers from their website, but it seems like there's still a hardware lock that prevents me from enabling wifi.  I'm using a hard line connection for now.

Here's what I get when I run the script:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4fKKPJ7QP7/

I've tried every other proposed solution, with no luck.  If anyone happens to have solved this before, I'd greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: What model Dell is it? Does the wireless switch not work? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: It's a Dell Precision 5510.  Pressed the wifi button several times before, but now that I've tried a few other things it seems to be working.

So thanks!  I should run through the checklist after every change next time...